# Array Push, expects parameter

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

Hi I am trying to push loop though and array and push it to my new array. I am currently getting this error..

**array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string**

I cannot work out why this is not working, my code looks like this.

```
    $data['text'] = array();
    foreach( $this->xml['paragraphs']['paragraph'] as $array )
    {
        array_push($array['text'], $data);
    }
```

My array

```
 [paragraphs] => Array
    (
        [paragraph] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Solid wood door leading to entrance hallway, doors leading to Lounge/ Dining room and Shower room, double radiator, solid wood frame sash window to front, painted wood panell ceiling with single light, Indian slate floor.
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [text] => Solid wood frame sash window to front, double radiator, bathroom suite comrising: shower cubicle with obscure perspex panells, WC and vanity sink. Painted wood panel ceiling with single light. Heated towel rail,
                    )
```

Comment: Are you mixing up `$data` and `$array`?

Comment: why do you avoid simple solutions like this: `$data[] = $array['text'];`?

Comment: No im not mixing it up im pushing it to the array

Comment: You are trying to push `array('text' => array())` into the string `"Solid wood..."`!

Comment: Man, why does ^ this ^ sound like a double entendre? O_o

Comment: @deceze I was always curious about what ^ this ^ means :D thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

array
    The input array.
var
    The pushed value.
```

it looks, to me, that you've reversed the two parameters. Assuming you're iterating over `$this->xml['paragraphs']['paragraph']` and trying to push each `$array['test']` result in to `$data`, it should look like this:

```
array_push($data, $array['text']);

// equivalent:
// $data[] = $array['text'];
```

Not the other way around.

Comment: @BrentFrench: No worries, we all start somewhere. ;-)